# In regard to pressure

Tags: grammar

"We will bid for the 12 projects next week via system, public bidding, the cost competitive pressure is bigger, can you make a concession on those prices?"

Can I say a pressure is bigger? If there is any other mistake in my sentence above, please help correct, thanks in advance.

Comment: I corrected a typo. Pubic (vs public) is NOT what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `bigger that what`? Maybe you want to say `the pressure is huge`.

I don't fully understand the gist of your statement, but I may change it like this:

"We will bid for the 12 projects next week via system- pubic bidding. The cost competitive pressure is huge, so can you make a concession on those prices?"

Answer (score 1):

Pressure would normally be "higher".

As for other mistakes, there definitely are because it's nonsensical, to a layperson at least. What is "system", what is the relationship of "public bidding" to the clauses before and after it ? I can guess the relationship between the last two clauses, but they seem weirdly juxtaposed to the first part of the sentence; should this maybe be two sentences ? Without knowing what you're trying to say it's hard to make suggestions for improvement.